# Will my Google App Engine Symfony 2 project be reusabe on a normal host later?

Tags: php, symfony, google-app-engine

I'm planning on using Google App Engine and I mainly use Symfony 2 for my projects.

In the documentation I've read that they have a "modified source code for Symfony Standard" and there's something with caching and read-only file system.

This wouldn't be a problem (I guess, because it's modified to work), but I wonder if I can reuse my application on a normal host (or using my bundles elsewhere).

What are the main differences between a GAE Symfony 2 project and a "normal" one?

Comment: Could you devise a file wrapper that uses a different writeable location depending on a configuration flag?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Well, if the difference between a GAE app and a standard app is that the former needs to write (cache) files to a remote server, then you need to find the component that does this and make it configurable. If one of your bundles needs to write a file, don't do it "the GAE way", do that with a wrapper class, so that you can move away from GAE if you wish.

Comment: I know I have to make "tricks" for things such as this, but my question was that what are the differences and not how to work around them. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about portability, you may want to check out AppEngine Managed VMs.  You use the same tools as AppEngine, but you get to control the full stack. It's currently in beta:

https://cloud.google.com/python/

You should be able to use this to run an unmodified version of Symfony 2.

Hope this helps!